# Reverse doubly-link list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, reverse

I've been trying to figure out how to reverse the order of a doubly-linked list, but for some reason, in my function `void reverse()` runs while loop once and then crashes for some reason.  To answer some questions ahead, I'm self-teaching myself with my brothers help.  This isn't all of the code, but I have a `display()` function which prints all nodes chronologically from `start_ptr` and a switch which activates certain functions like

```
    case 1 : add_end(); break;
    case 2 : add_begin(); break;
    case 3 : add_index(); break;
    case 4 : del_end(); break;
    case 5 : del_begin(); break;
    case 6 : reverse(); break;
```

This is the geist of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char name[20];
    char profession[20];
    int age;
    node *nxt;
    node *prv;
};

node *start_ptr = NULL;

void pswap (node *pa, node *pb)
{
    node temp = *pa;
    *pa = *pb;
    *pb = temp;
    return;
}

void reverse()
{
    if(start_ptr==NULL)
    {
        cout << "Can't do anything" << endl;
    }
    else if(start_ptr->nxt==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        node *current = start_ptr;
        node *nextone = start_ptr;
        nextone=nextone->nxt->nxt;
        current=current->nxt;
        start_ptr->prv=start_ptr->nxt;
        start_ptr->nxt=NULL;
        //nextone=nextone->nxt;
        while(nextone->nxt!= NULL)
        {
            pswap(current->nxt, current->prv);
            current=nextone;
            nextone=nextone->nxt;
        }
        start_ptr=nextone;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're swapping the contents of the nodes rather than just the node pointers.  Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: On a related note, you could look at the things from a different point of view.  Rather than reverse the contents of the doubly-linked list itself, you could instead focus on iterating over the contents of the list in reverse, which should be straightforward since the list is doubly-linked.  For example, implement STL-style bidirectional iterators for your list.  They can be used with the `std::reverse_iterator<>` adapter (for `rbegin()` and `rend()`).  Once those methods are implemented it'll be simple to leverage the STL algorithms, including `std::reverse()`.  It's a fun exercise, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
node *ptr = start_ptr;
while (ptr != NULL) {
    node *tmp = ptr->nxt;
    ptr->nxt = ptr->prv;
    ptr->prv = tmp;
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        end_ptr = start_ptr;
        start_ptr = ptr;
    }
    ptr = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Best one, though I'm having a brain fart because you didn't end the list with the pointer addressed to NULL

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot man, I fixed your code up a bit and it looks so much prettier than all my other attempts. All you had to do was add a qualification when `start_ptr==NULL || start_ptr->nxt==NULL` and make your part of the code the else end.  Within that, I made sure at the end code, `end_ptr->nxt=NULL;` Thanks a bunch

Comment: I'm not really sure why you need those checks - I think the code I gave will work fine without them.  And at the end, end_ptr->nxt will be NULL because at the start, start_ptr->prv was NULL.  But you're welcome, at any rate.

Comment: @Borealid can't we just assign `head` pointer to the last node and `NULL` to `prv` of starting node?

Comment: @Dan : I know 9 years have passe, but - `end_ptr` is not defined anywhere. Did you make that change?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: My first implementation, which was correct but not perfect.**
Your implementation is pretty complicated. Can you try this instead:

```
node * reverse(Node * start_ptr)
{
    Node *curr = start_ptr; 
    Node * prev = null;
    Node * next = null;
    while(curr)
    {
        next = curr->nxt;
        curr->nxt = prev;
    curr->prv = next;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    return start_ptr=prev;
}
```

**Here is my updated solution:**

```
node * reverse()
{
    node *curr = start_ptr; 
    node * prev = NULL;
    node * next = NULL;
    while(curr)
    {
        next = curr->nxt;
        curr->nxt = prev;
        curr->prv = next;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    return start_ptr=prev;
}
```

The logic was correct. But the issue was that I was accepting in input argument start_ptr. Which means that I was returning the local copy of it. Now it should be working.

Comment: I just can't figure out how I might be doing that.
Can anyone confirm if this implementation creates a circular linked list?
Thanks...

Comment: Hi Danutenshu, I have updated my solution. 
I know your issues is already solved, but I would feel much better if you can please let me know if what I have changed is correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your `reverse()` quite a bit.  I'd do something like this:

```
void reverse()
{
    if(start_ptr == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Can't do anything" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        node *curr = start_ptr;
        while(curr != NULL)
        {
            Node *next = curr->next;
            curr->next = curr->prev;
            curr->prev = next;
            curr = next;
        }
        start_ptr = prev;       
    }
}
```

Explanation:  The basic idea is simply to visit each `Node` and swap the links to `previous` and `next`.  When we move `curr` to the next `Node`, we need to store the next node so we still have a pointer to it when we set `curr.next` to `prev`.

Comment: I think you missed updating the first node's prev to be the second node.

Comment: Indeed, and I was off-by-one at the start.  Should be better now.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution. reverses in less than half a number of total iterations over the list

```
template<typename E> void DLinkedList<E>::reverse() {
    int median = 0;
    int listSize = size();
    int counter = 0;

    if (listSize == 1)
    return;

    DNode<E>* tempNode = new DNode<E>();

    /**
     * A temporary node for swapping a node and its reflection node
     */
    DNode<E>* dummyNode = new DNode<E>();

    DNode<E>* headCursor = head;
    DNode<E>* tailCursor = tail;

    for (int i = 0; i < listSize / 2; i++) {
        cout << i << "\t";

        headCursor = headCursor->next;
        tailCursor = tailCursor->prev;

        DNode<E>* curNode = headCursor;
        DNode<E>* reflectionNode = tailCursor;

        if (listSize % 2 == 0 && listSize / 2 - 1 == i) {
            /**
             * insert a dummy node for reflection
         * for even sized lists
         */
        curNode->next = dummyNode;
        dummyNode->prev = curNode;

        reflectionNode->prev = dummyNode;
        dummyNode->next = reflectionNode;

    }
    /**
     * swap the connections from previous and 
             * next nodes for current and reflection nodes
     */

    curNode->prev->next = curNode->next->prev = reflectionNode;

    reflectionNode->prev->next = reflectionNode->next->prev = curNode;

    /**
     * swapping of the nodes
     */

    tempNode->prev = curNode->prev;
    tempNode->next = curNode->next;

    curNode->next = reflectionNode->next;
    curNode->prev = reflectionNode->prev;

    reflectionNode->prev = tempNode->prev;
    reflectionNode->next = tempNode->next;

    if (listSize % 2 == 0 && listSize / 2 - 1 == i) {
        /**
         * remove a dummy node for reflection
         * for even sized lists
         */
        reflectionNode->next = curNode;
        curNode->prev = reflectionNode;
    }

    /**
     * Reassign the cursors to position over the recently swapped nodes
     */
        tailCursor = curNode;
        headCursor = reflectionNode;

    }

    delete tempNode, dummyNode;
}

template<typename E> int DLinkedList<E>::size() {
    int count = 0;
    DNode<E>* iterator = head;

    while (iterator->next != tail) {
        count++;
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pswap function is wrong
your should swap the pointer not try to create temporary objects and swap them.
Should be like that (there might be other mistake later)

```
void pswap (node *&pa, node *&pb)
{
    node* temp = pa;
    pa = pb;
    pb = temp;
    return;
}
```

Comment: That won't actually do anything.  You need to pass pointers to pointers or references to pointers so the changes apply to the original objects, not local copies.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I didn't look at the signature function. Just fixed the temporary object creation mistake

Answer (score 0):

I suggest maintaining a link to the last node.
If not, find the last node.
Traverse the list using the "previous" links (or in your case, `prv`).

There is no need to actually change the links around.  Traversing using the `prv` pointer will automatically visit the nodes in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Look at

```
valuesnextone=nextone->nxt->nxt;
```

Here `nextone->nxt` can be null.

Apart from that, try to use pointers to pointers in the swap function.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and O(n) solution using two pointers:

start = head of the doubly LL

```
struct node *temp, *s;
s = start;

while(s != NULL){
  temp = s->prev;
  s->prev = s->next;
  s->next = temp;
  s = s->prev;
}

//if list has more than one node
if(current != NULL){
  start = temp->prev;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code for reversing doubly linked list,

```
Node* Reverse(Node* head)
{
// Complete this function
// Do not write the main method. 


if(head != NULL) {

    Node* curr = head;
    Node* lastsetNode = curr;
    while(curr != NULL) {

        Node* frwdNode = curr->next;
        Node* prevNode = curr->prev;


        if(curr==head) {                
            curr->next = NULL;
            curr->prev = frwdNode;
            lastsetNode = curr;
        }
        else {
            curr->next = lastsetNode;
            curr->prev = frwdNode;
            lastsetNode = curr;
        }



        curr = frwdNode;
    }

    head = lastsetNode;
}


return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add a recursive solution here.

```cpp
node* reverse_and_get_new_head(node* head) {
    if (head == nullptr) { return nullptr; } 
      // This can be avoided by ensuring the initial,
      // outer call is with a non-empty list
    std::swap(head->prev, head->next);
    if (head->prev == nullptr) { return head; }
    return reverse_and_get_new_head(head->prev);
}

void reverse() {
    start_ptr = reverse_and_get_new_head(start_ptr);
}
```